# Python 3.6 NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am new to python. I am getting a NameEror when I run this code. I am not using any kind of input() or variable type selection etc.

I had run the same scrip the previous night without any problems!

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


with open('URLs.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        url = row ['URL']
        r  = requests.get(url)

        data = r.text

        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")

        td = soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'C($gray) Ta(end)'}) 
        datalist = td
        #x = None        
        for link in datalist[::-1]:
            x = (link.find_all('span')[0])
        print(x.text, ",",row['Ticker'])
```

Comment: remove `#x=None` from your code make it `x=None`

Comment: The CSV contains urls and their tickerTicker, URL
BSCA, https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BSCA/financials?p=BSCA

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis That is not his problem. Python allows you to define a variable in a loop.

Comment: This means that the loop is never run. `datalist` is empty.

Comment: @ChristianDean , you are right but just in case...

Comment: @StavrosAvramidI have commented out the #x=None section

Comment: what is x supposed to be?

Comment: Did you want to run the print within the for loop?

Comment: @ aryamccarthy Bingo! you are right. the 0th  element is []. So, this was throwing up an error.

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis x is supposed to be the last span element in the parsed section

Comment: @cricket_007 I only need the last section. So, the print is meant to be outside the forloop.

Comment: But you only defined x *within the loop*

Comment: Problem is solved @ aryamccarthy. 'datalist' was indeed empty. Thank you all for pitching in to help. you guys solved it under 10 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage's DOM is not the same as other pages. as a result 'code' x = (link.find_all('span')[0]) 'code' was having any value. Hence the NameError.

(see comments)

what changed from yesterday to today? the URL list. This is the reason the code was running yesterday and not running today.

The code can be improved with appropriate error handling.